# Perfect background fit with dynamic page height (Mobile)- CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile, background

I'm working on a little project (a pseudo-web app that can be used from PC, Tablet or Smartphone).

I've done basically everything that my immagination has suggested, expect one thing: background. The result that I want to achieve it's a background (It's a beach photo, not a pattern) that would 'fit' the entire screen,depending the device from which it's seen.

Isn't a problem (I've seen some cool technics) but...

The site can be scrolled vertically: on page load everything go fine but when I add more content to the page (AJAX) the site add more content to the page and 'INCREASE' page height.

So every CSS propriety that I've seen (like `background-size: cover`) , on page 'reload', do a VERY annoing effect on the background,that it's 'reloaded' with new page height and it's very ugly to see. On PC it's basically OK, but on mobile device (Every) this do a horrible layout breaking also.

Another way it's to fix my background on top of the page; it's ok,until I scroll enough to reach the end of the picture.

Any way to achieve a reliable effect to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You can add these styles to a div or whatever. For demo purposes I used `<body>`. If you don't want the image to scroll with the page change `background-attachment: scroll;` to `background-attachment: fixed;`

**EDIT:**

I went ahead and added `background-size: 100% 100%;` so the entire image displays correctly.

```css
body{
background-image: url("http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2013/6-starfish-seashells-beach-sand-wallpaper.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I want to add a background to the body, so I'm adding all CSS to the body{} selector.

Using |background-attachment: scroll | doesn't work: on PC if the page doesn't have a lot of element (they fill only half the screen initially) I saw the background image only on the half of the screen. Pretty ugly.

Using | background-attachment|: fixed; work, but I've the same problem:
when the page grow horizontally the background got stretched. (Probably caused by background-size: 100% 100%;)

Comment: Hmm give me a sec let me see what I can do @AlexDG

Comment: I've done an error: the background got stretched when I grow it VERTICALLY , not horizontally (In fact the page can't scroll in horizontal way).

Comment: I changed the sizing from `background-size: 100% 100%` to `background-size: cover;`. Let me know if that helps. @AlexDG

Comment: Ahh I see. Well if my answer helped you please tick that checkmark please :) @AlexDG

Comment: Tried it and work good. On PC it's perfect, on android it 'move' the background depending on number of on-screen content. On iphone can't get it work (it's move brutally the background when page grow).

Answer (score 0):

Making your div position:fixed and give the full width to it. Try this code snap. It should helpful to you.

```css
#background{
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}

html { 
  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Is this answer, are you expect?

Comment: I've tried it but doesn't seem to work like I expected: with that I can't scroll the page, even If there's content below.